# Pre-sorted Per-pixel Linked List using Metal Shader

Tags: 3d, shader, render, fragment-shader, metal

Does Metal shading language support the pre-sorted per-pixel linked-list such as the one descriptor in *GPU Pro 5*?

I know the Metal supports atomic variable so from that I think it does support linear-allocation and post-sorting which sorts the data in a shader's local memory. But I haven't seen the same synchronization operation over a buffer in Metal like the one shown in some DirectX examples.

Thanks @warrenm for providing the link to download the code. http://www.antexel.com/sylefeb-research/gpupro5/

The key issue is `atomicMax64()`. I haven't found anything like that function in Metal shading language, so wondering that's a missing piece.

Comment: For others' reference, the implementation described in _GPU Pro 5_ can be found [here](http://www.antexel.com/sylefeb-research/gpupro5/).

Comment: @warrenm Seems the answer comes out in WWDC 2017. Metal 2 seems the answer.

Comment: Did you resolve this with Metal 2?

Comment: @basbiston Yes. The way of synchronization, which I mentioned in the question and doubted Metal lacks, was indeed not existing in Metal, and then introduced in Metal 2.